# Backgrounding a shell command that was executed via system / exec - same as in bash (&)?

Tags: php, background, system, exec

Is it possible to background a shell command that is executed via system / exec?

Like in bash:

```
/bin/command &
```

Would the following do the same:

```
system('/bin/command &');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will be the same as the bash, as the text is sent directly to the command line but it's limited to the user permissions for the user that allocated to php & apache

so you should check user permissions to access these command.